# Powershell to check usage of a custom Permission Level

Tags: 2010, permissions, custom

As the title says I need to find/write a Powershell script that will look through all of my Site Collection to see where a specific (custom) Permissions Level is being used.

All the articles I have found are about creating or editing permission levels with Powershell.

Thanks
mtwelve

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar script on technet forums:

```
#$path = get-location
$sites = get-spsite "http://SP2010/site/sam/"
foreach ($site in $sites)
 {

    write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$site.RootWeb.Title "..."
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
     {
      foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
      {
 write-host -foregroundcolor green "Group Name: "$roleAssignment.Member.Name "..."

           foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                {
                    write-host -foregroundcolor red "Permission Name: "$roleDefinition.Name "..."
                }

      }

     }
      $web.Dispose()
 }


$site.Dispose()
```

You can modify this script to check the role instead of just print it out.

[SOURCE](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/6c502cd5-04a0-4b9e-a35a-dd7e9cd6d431)

Answer (score 2):

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added
 if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
 Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
 } 

#Define variables
 $site = Get-SPSite "http://sitecoll"

#Get all subsites for site collection
 $web = $site.AllWebs

#Loop through each subsite and write permissions

foreach ($web in $web)
 {
 if (($web.permissions -ne $null) -and ($web.hasuniqueroleassignments -eq "True"))
 {
 Write-Output "****************************************"
 Write-Output "Displaying site permissions for: $web"
 $web.roledefinitions | fl Name
 }

#Loop through each list in each subsite and get permissions

foreach ($list in $web.lists)
 {
 $unique = $list.hasuniqueroleassignments
 if (($list.permissions -ne $null) -and ($unique -eq "True"))
 {
 Write-Output "****************************************"
 Write-Output "Displaying Lists permissions for: $web \ $list"
 $list.roleassignments | fl roledefinitionbindings
 }
 }
 }
 Write-Host "Finished."
 $site.dispose()
 $web.dispose()
```

Run it as

```
 C:>./script.ps1 | out-file C:/permissions.txt
```

Then you CTRL+F search for the definition you are looking for.

I modified this script from [here](http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2011/08/powershell-script-to-display-unique-permissions-for-all-subsites-and-lists/)

Comment: He may also need to loop through items in each list as well.